# Slow request with simple query in Laravel using Axios

Tags: php, laravel, axios

I'm making a request with Axios and the time it takes for making a request is approximately ~1.21s.

This is my sample controller for the delete method.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $business = Business::findOrFail($id);
    if($business->delete())
    {
        return new BusinessResource($business);
    }
}
```

And this is my Axios script.

```
deleteBusiness: function(id)
{
    let vm = this;
    axios.delete('api/business/'+id)
    .then(function (response){
        alert("Business Deleted");
        vm.fetchBusiness();
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });   
},
```

This is my model, implementing Laravel Scout & TNTSearch:.

```php
namespace App;  

use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Business extends Model
{
    use Searchable;

    protected $table = 'business';

    public function toSearchableArray()
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'businessName' => $this->businessName,
        ];
    }

    public function searchableAs()
    {
        return 'business_index';
    }
}
```

When I remove the `use Searchable` in the model, the request time reduces to approximately ~300ms. Is there any way to reduce the time of this request without removing the `use Searchable` in the model? Do I need to use Redis?

Comment: Why are you returning a resource from the destroy method? A 204 - indicating no content - would be more appropriate.

Comment: okay sir i removed it

Comment: What search is scout using? If it's a 3rd party off-site service then you'd need to wait until the delete is reflected there as well

Comment: TNTsearch. I see but is there anyway to speed things up?

Comment: If you're not using queues for scout, that's your problem. Any request using the searchable trait will run time consuming requests to update indexes if these are not queued. If you implement queueing these will not take place on each request.

Comment: I see sir. But i already set to true the queue in scout it is still the same lol. But right now im gonna stick to my built in custom search. I didn't know that's gonna happen i just tried the scout + tnt search driver. Thanks btw